# Show that if $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $, $\mathrm{tr}(A^{k}) = \mathrm{tr}(A^{k-1}) + \mathrm{tr}(A^{k-2})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> $\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}$ If $A =   \begin{bmatrix}
>      0 & 1  \\
>      1 & 1    \end{bmatrix} $, then $\tr(A^{k}) = \tr(A^{k-1}) + \tr(A^{k-2})$.
>
> Hint: If $AB=0$, then $\tr[(A+B)^k]=\tr(A^k)+\tr(B^k)$.

I tried to decompose \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1  \\
    1 & 1 
  \end{bmatrix} to $P$ and $Q$ such that $P+Q=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1  \\
    1 & 1 
  \end{bmatrix}$ and $PQ=0$, but it seems that this does not work.

Comment: In this question, the professor gives the hint that: if $AB = 0$, then $tr[(A + B)^{k}] = tr(A^{k}) + tr(B^{k})$.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, Joel, I tried to decompose $  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    1 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}$ to $A$ and $B$ such that $A + B = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    1 & 1
  \end{bmatrix} $ and $AB = 0$, but it seems that this does not work.

Comment: [probably not the way the hint wants you to go] --- have you learned how to diagonalize matrices yet?

Comment: Hi, Joel, we proved the following theorem on diagonalization in this week's class: every real symmetric matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: Hi, Thomas, I think the result holds for all $k \geq 2$.

Comment: Hint: Show that $A^2=A+I_2$. Multiply this equation by ____

Comment: It holds for $k \geq 2$.  It's closely related to the Fibbonacci sequence.

Comment: Indeed, @Joel. My suspicion is that we have already covered this exercise on the site (due to the connection to Fibonacci). Arthur, did you search?

Comment: Hi, @JyrkiLahtonen, I searched, but did not find a relevant post on this.

Comment: See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2525592/11619). Not that you need the connection to do this.

Comment: It may still be a good idea to include relevant pieces of background to the question **body**. We are all happy to see that you can use a hint :-) But, in isolation, the question looks like a copy/pasted homework assignment. Those may attract negative attention. Some tips for new askers were collected [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Comment: Hi, @JyrkiLahtonen, thanks for your advice on how to ask questions! It is very helpful!

Comment: Also, leaving your teacher's hint visible may be a good idea. It may be their favorite trick, and you may re-encounter it later, like in the final exam. So it is definitely a good idea to have that path explored more thoroughly as well :-)

Comment: Does anyone have any luck with using that hint? The solution using the characteristic polynomial is super-elementary, while coming up (1) with a decomposition of $A$ into $P+Q$ and then (2) using the hint to expand the trace, (3) finishing by some induction seems to be much harder.

Comment: Not really @daw. The connection to Fibonacci numbers means that $tr(A^k)$ is a linear combination of powers of $(1\pm\sqrt5)/2$, and it is not clear to me how to get that using the hint (other than by diagnolizing $A$). I urged the OP to leave that in mainly to have some context in the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thank for the help! I think I figured it out. Here is my proof.

Proof: First note that $A^{2} = A + I_{2}$. Thus, for $A^{k}$:
\begin{align}
A^{k} &= A^{k-2} \cdot A^{2} \\
&= A^{k-2}(A + I_{2}) \\
&= A^{k-1} + A^{k-2}.
\end{align}
Then, for $\operatorname{tr}(A^{k})$:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}(A^{k}) &= \operatorname{tr}(A^{k-1} + A^{k-2}) \\
&= \operatorname{tr}(A^{k-1}) + \operatorname{tr}(A^{k-2}),
\end{align}
where the last equality follows from the fact that trace is a linear map.

Comment: Good job! ${}{}$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: by the way - do you know how you could have found $A^2=A+I$?  Write down the characteristic equation of $A$.  There's a theorem that says a matrix always satisfies its own characteristic equation.

Answer (score 1):

I think your teacher has given a bad hint. It is far easier and more natural to solve the problem using the characteristic equation of $A$, as the comment  of  Jyrki Lahtonen or the other answer show. Anyway, we shall demystify your teacher's hint below. We suppose that the integer $k$ in question is nonnegative.

We first validate the statement in the hint. When $k\ge1$ and $XY=0$, the binomial expansion of $(X+Y)^k$ will be the sum of $X^k,\,Y^k$ and a number of interlaced products of $X$s and $Y$s. If an interlaced product contains $XY$ in its product sequence (such as $XXYXY$), the product as well as its trace are zero; if the product sequence doesn't contain $XY$, it must be of the form $Y^jX^{n-j}$ with $0<j<n$, and hence by the tracial property, $\operatorname{tr}(Y^jX^{n-j})=\operatorname{tr}(X^{n-j}Y^j)=0$. In other words, the trace of every interlaced product is zero. Thus we do have $\operatorname{tr}\left((X+Y)^k\right)=\operatorname{tr}(X^k)+\operatorname{tr}(Y^k)$.

Next, we want to decompose $A$ into $X+Y$ with $XY=0$. There are at least two ways to do this. The first way is to perform an eigendecomposition $A=V\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)V^{-1}$ (this is possible because $A$ is real symmetric) and take $X=V\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,0)V^{-1},\,Y=V\operatorname{diag}(0,\lambda_2)V^{-1}$.

The second way is to solve $X(A-X)=0$. Note that if $X$ is invertible, we will get a useless solution $X=A$ and $Y=A-X=A$. So, we must assume that $X$ is singular but nonzero. Write $X=uv^T$. The equation $X(A-X)=0$ hence becomes $uv^T(A-uv^T)=0$, which can be rewritten as $uv^T(A-(v^Tu)I)=0$, meaning that $A$ is a left eigenpair $(\lambda,v)$ for some $\lambda$ and $u$ is a vector such that $v^Tu=\lambda$. It is not hard to see that we may pick $\lambda=\frac12(1+\sqrt{5})$ and $v=(1,\lambda)^T$. To make $v^Tu=\lambda$, we choose $u=(0,\frac1{\lambda})^T$. Thus
$$
A=X+Y=\pmatrix{0&0\\ 1&\lambda}+\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&1-\lambda},\quad XY=0,
$$
and by your teacher's hint, $\operatorname{tr}(A^k)=\lambda^k+(1-\lambda)^k$ for every $k\ge1$. One can verify that this equality also holds for $k=0$. Thus the problem boils down to proving that
$$
\lambda^{k+2}+(1-\lambda)^{k+2}
=\left[\lambda^{k+1}+(1-\lambda)^{k+1}\right]
+\left[\lambda^k+(1-\lambda)^k\right]
$$
or that
$$
\left(\lambda^{k+2}-\lambda^{k+1}-\lambda^k\right)+
\left[(1-\lambda)^{k+2}-(1-\lambda)^{k+1}-(1-\lambda)^k\right]=0,
$$
but this is evident because both $\lambda$ and $1-\lambda$ are roots of $x^2-x-1=0$.